# Cannot add new partition using fdisk - No free sectors available

Tags: linux, partition

I would like to add new partitions to sda3, but fdisk says "No free sectors available". What can I do? [image]

Comment: Buy a new disk? Your disk is fully occupied. Do you want to split an existing partition? What do you currently have on the existing partitions?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no installed filesystem with software youNo free sectors available want to preserve, you can delete sda3 and recreate it as a smaller partition and then add a new one (possible in an extended partition).

If sda3 contains software it depends on whether it contains your running Linux or not. In both cases you will have to shrink the existing sda3 partition after you have shrunk the existing filesystem on it.

If sda3 is not where you have booted from you can shrink the filesystem, or copy it to a temporary drive, then remove sda3, recreate it smaller and copy the material back. Or you can look into shrinking the filesystem (whether that is possible depends on the filesystem type) and then shrink sda3.

If sda3 is where you booted from, you probably cannot do this on the mounted partition. In that case you can boot from CD or USB and proceed the same way as describe above for non-booted.

If this is a remote machine and you cannot boot from CD or USB, things are a bit more complicated but still possible. In that case the steps are:

- deactivate swap and change sda2 to type 83
- format the swap partition as a normal linux partition and install linux (copying a minimal system that fits) and make it bootable.
- boot from sda2 and proceed to change sda3
- reboot from the new sda3
- setup sda2 as swap once more

All of these, and the latter in particular have a high chance to break things if you make a mistake. (I actually performed the latter 'boot-from-swap-parttition'  on my colocated server running Ubuntu 8.04, so it for sure can be done, but newer versions of Linux have higher footprint).